# Using textscan to extract values from a text file

Tags: matlab, text, import, textscan, read-text

I have the following text file:

```
  Leaf Tips:2867.5,1101.66666666667 2555,764.166666666667 2382.5,1221.66666666667 2115,759.166666666667 1845,1131.66666666667 1270,991.666666666667 
  Leaf Bases:1682.66666666667,800.333333333333 1886,850.333333333333 2226,920.333333333333 2362.66666666667,923.666666666667 2619.33333333333,967 
  Ear Tips:1029.33333333333,513.666666666667 1236,753.666666666667 
  Ear Bases:1419.33333333333,790.333333333333 1272.66666666667,677
```

These are coordinates to regions of interest for each category in an image. I need to extract these regions. I know I have to use `textscan` to accomplish this but I am unsure of the `formatspec` options needed to achieve this, since whichever setting I use seem to give me some jumbled form of cell output.

What `formatSpec` should I use so that I get the coordinates of each region outputed in a cell?

I've tried the following:

```
file = '0.txt';
fileID = fopen(file);
formatSpec = '%s %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f';
C = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 150, 'Delimiter', ':');
```

Comment: For the example file you show, what would the desired output be, exactly?

Comment: @LuisMendo, to extract all the pixel coordinates, for example the first row should contain all the leaf tips coordinates i.e. ``2867.5,1101.66666666667``, ``2555,764.166666666667`` and so on and the second row should be a cell containing all the leaf bases coordinates.. I want to use these coordinates to extract these regions from the image file

Comment: And what's the desired content of each cell? A numeric row vector? A 2-column matrix?

Comment: A two column matrix would be great as each cell would contain a single coordinate. So what I wanted the ``textscan`` to output was a 4 row cell array, the first row would have 6 cells representing the coordinates of the 6 regions for that specific row(in this case leaf tips). And the second row would have 5 cells, representing the coordinates of the leaf bases, and each cell would be a 2 column matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of what you can do:

```
fid = fopen('0.txt');                    % open file
T = textscan(fid, '%s','Delimiter',':'); % read all lines, separate row names from numbers
fclose(fid);                             % close file
T = reshape(T{1},2,[]).';                % rearrange outputs so it makes more sense
T = [T(:,1), cellfun(@(x)textscan(x,'%f','Delimiter',','), T(:,2))]; % parse numbers
```

Which will result in a cell array as follows:

```
T =

  4×2 cell array

    {'Leaf Tips' }    {12×1 double}
    {'Leaf Bases'}    {10×1 double}
    {'Ear Tips'  }    { 4×1 double}
    {'Ear Bases' }    { 4×1 double}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
x = textscan(fid,'%s', 'Delimiter', char(10)); % read each line
fclose(fid);
x = x{1};
x = regexp(x, '\d*\.?\d*', 'match'); % extract numbers of each line
C = cellfun(@(t) reshape(str2double(t), 2, []).', x, 'UniformOutput', false); % rearrange
```

Result:

```
>> celldisp(C)
C{1} =
   1.0e+03 *
   2.867500000000000   1.101666666666670
   2.555000000000000   0.764166666666667
   2.382500000000000   1.221666666666670
   2.115000000000000   0.759166666666667
   1.845000000000000   1.131666666666670
   1.270000000000000   0.991666666666667
C{2} =
   1.0e+03 *
   1.682666666666670   0.800333333333333
   1.886000000000000   0.850333333333333
   2.226000000000000   0.920333333333333
   2.362666666666670   0.923666666666667
   2.619333333333330   0.967000000000000
C{3} =
   1.0e+03 *
   1.029333333333330   0.513666666666667
   1.236000000000000   0.753666666666667
C{4} =
   1.0e+03 *
   1.419333333333330   0.790333333333333
   1.272666666666670   0.677000000000000
```

Comment: @ipunished please accept an answer (for example, this one) to indicate that your problem is solved.

Comment: @ipunished Note that I assumed a specific format for the numbers (for example, no negative sign). Dev-iL's answer is more general, as he uses `%f`

Comment: Both of them do exactly what I wanted and both answers were posted at the same time, so I have a tough time selecting best answer. But thank you @LuisMendo for helping me make this decision. Many thanks for your input and help :)